# Python WMI - can we really say that 'C:' is always the boot drive?

Tags: python, wmi

I am working on a task to find the boot drive among list of SSDs connected.
Trying to get it by matching device path("\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0") of drives with logical disk partition using WMI.

Here is my code:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()

for physical_disk in w.Win32_DiskDrive():
     if physical_disk.DeviceID == "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0":
           for partition in physical_disk.associators("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"):
                        for logical in partition.associators("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
                            if logical.caption == 'C:':
                               print "Its a boot drive"
                               break
```

I feel like just checking if we are looking at the c-drive is not quite enough. I feel like this can go wrong... Are we assured that 'C:' is always the boot drive? It probably is most of the time, but can we really say that 'C:' is always the boot drive?

Can we have a more robust way to ensure the drive we are looking at is a boot drive?

Answer (score 0):

***Can we have a more robust way to ensure the drive we are looking at is a boot drive?*** We could numerate *all* disks/partitions/volumes as follows:

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()

print ( "\r\nnamespace='root/CIMV2' -> Win32_DiskDrive" )
csvlike='{0:>2}`{1:18}`{2:21}`{3:>5}`{4:>5}`{5:1}`{6:1}`{7}'
# print header
print ( csvlike.format( 'dl',
    'diskDeviceID',
    'partitionDeviceID',
    'BootA',
    'Activ',
    'd',
    'p',
    'diskSerialNumber'))
for w32_disk in w.Win32_DiskDrive():
  auxpart = w32_disk.associators("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition")
  if len( auxpart) == 0:
    print ( csvlike.format( '',w32_disk.DeviceID,'','','',
              w32_disk.Index,'',w32_disk.SerialNumber))
  else:
    for w32_part in auxpart:
      auxlogic = w32_part.associators("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")
      if len(auxlogic) == 0:
        print ( csvlike.format( '', w32_disk.DeviceID,
            w32_part.DeviceID,
            str(w32_part.Bootable)      if w32_part.Bootable      else '',
            str(w32_part.BootPartition) if w32_part.BootPartition else '',
            str(w32_part.DiskIndex),       # == w32_disk.Index
            str(w32_part.Index),
            w32_disk.SerialNumber))
      else:
        for w32_ldsk in auxlogic:
          print ( csvlike.format( w32_ldsk.caption,
            w32_disk.DeviceID,
            w32_part.DeviceID,
            str(w32_part.Bootable)      if w32_part.Bootable      else '',
            str(w32_part.BootPartition) if w32_part.BootPartition else '',
            str(w32_part.DiskIndex),    # == w32_disk.Index == party.DiskNumber
            str(w32_part.Index),        # == party.PartitionNumber -1
            w32_disk.SerialNumber))

print ( "\r\nnamespace='root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage' -> MSFT_Disk" )
s = wmi.WMI(namespace='root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage')
csvheader='{0:2}`{1:>5}`{2:>5}`{3:>5}`{4:1}`{5:1}`{6:38}`{7}'
print ( csvheader.format( 'dl', 'Syst', 'Boot', 'Activ', 'd', 'p',
          'volumeUniqueId (truncated to UUID)', 'SerialNumber' ) )
for d in s.MSFT_Disk():
  dps=d.associators("MSFT_DiskToPartition")
  for party in dps:
    auxvolumy = party.associators("MSFT_PartitionToVolume")
    if len( auxvolumy) == 0:
      print ( csvheader.format(
          '',
          str( party.IsSystem ) if party.IsSystem         else '',
          str( party.IsBoot )   if party.IsBoot           else '',
          str( party.IsActive ) if ( d.PartitionStyle==1
                                  and party.IsActive )    else '' ,
          str( party.DiskNumber ),      # == w32_disk.Index
          str( party.PartitionNumber ), # == w32_part.Index +1
          '',
          d.SerialNumber))
    else:
      for volumy in auxvolumy:
        print ( csvheader.format(
          chr( volumy.DriveLetter ) if volumy.DriveLetter else '',
          str( party.IsSystem ) if party.IsSystem         else '',
          str( party.IsBoot )   if party.IsBoot           else '',
          str( party.IsActive ) if ( d.PartitionStyle==1
                                  and party.IsActive )    else '' ,
          str( party.DiskNumber ),      # == w32_disk.Index
          str( party.PartitionNumber ), # == w32_part.Index +1
          volumy.UniqueId[10:][:38],  # .replace('\\?\Volume','')
          d.SerialNumber))



print ( "\r\nnamespace='root/CIMV2' -> Win32_Volume" )
csvheaderwv='{0:2}`{1:>5}`{2:>5}`{3:>5}`{4}'
# print header
print ( csvheaderwv.format( 'dl',
    'Syst',
    'Boot',
    'PageF',
    'volumeDeviceID'))
volumes = w.Win32_Volume()
for volume in volumes:
  print( csvheaderwv.format(
    volume.DriveLetter         if volume.DriveLetter  else '',
    str( volume.SystemVolume ) if volume.SystemVolume else '',
    str( volume.BootVolume )   if volume.BootVolume   else '',
    str( volume.PagefilePresent )   if volume.PagefilePresent   else '',
    volume.DeviceID ))
```

***Are we assured that `C:` is always the boot drive?*** Pay your attention to the read-only environment variables [`SystemDrive` and `SystemRoot`](https://superuser.com/a/638335/376602):

> … `%SystemRoot%` is a built-in variable (along with a small handful of
>   others like `%SystemDrive%`). That is, it is not actually defined in the
>   environment variable store at
>   `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` in
>   the registry… In addition, `%SystemRoot%` (and `%SystemDrive%`) are set
>   during the installation process (when you choose the destination
>   drive)…

Both above variables are set during windows boot and you can see their origin running from an *elevated* command prompt (see [Boot Configuration Data (BCD) data stores](https://ss64.com/nt/bcdedit.html)):

```
bcdedit /enum ACTIVE
```

**Various sources** (with basic terminology on *active*/*system*/*boot* partition):

[Win32 Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-provider): `Win32_DiskPartition` class

- `Bootable` property indicates whether the computer can be booted from this partition.

  If TRUE, the disk partition is labeled as bootable. This does not mean that an operating system is loaded on the partition.
- `BootPartition` property. Partition is the active partition. The operating system uses the active partition when booting from a hard disk.

[Storage Volume Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/storage-volume-provider) (deprecated?): `Win32_Volume` class (no direct relationship exists between `Win32_Volume` and `Win32_DiskDrive`.)

- `SystemVolume` property indicates whether the volume contains the hardware specific files required to start the operating system.
- `BootVolume` property indicates whether the volume contains the currently running operating system files.

[Storage Management API Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/storage-management-api-classes) (deprecated?): `MSFT_Partition` class

- `IsActive` property signifies whether or not the partition is active and can be booted. This property is only relevant for MBR disks.

  If TRUE, the **partition is active** and can be used to start the system. This property is only valid when the disk's `PartitionStyle` property is MBR (i.e. MSFT_Disk.PartitionStyle==1) and will be NULL for all other partition styles.
- `IsBoot` property. If TRUE, the partition is the current **boot partition**.

  The boot partition is the partition that holds the Windows installation.
- `IsSystem` property. If TRUE, this is a **system partition**.

  The system partition contains the files that your Windows needs to start (the Boot Configuration Data or BCD). The reserved partitions (or the system partitions) do not have a letter assigned to them.